# How to extract the word from sentence

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I'm new in `NLP` and I want to create model to accomplish this task

My data is in Persian language

I want to extract this entity from sentence like this

```
sentence = 'I bought 3 red apples from Bingo store'
sentence = 'من سه تا سیب قرمز از فروشگاه بینگو خریدم' //Persian
```

I want this entity's

```
product = 'red appel'
unit count = '3'
location = 'Bingo store'
-------------------------
product = 'سیب قرمز'
unit count = '3'
location = 'فروشگاه بینگو'
```

Comment: I believe the process is known as Semantic Role Labeling am I right or what? Is there any Dataset Available in Farsi?

Comment: @meti no i don't think, but can i use the token classification for this problem?

Comment: The nearest solution which relates to Token Classification and can be used in your problem is NER or even Entity Recognition (not Named Entity). @miladjurablu

Comment: @meti tnx man  i prishiate